# Detect equal elements in a std::list

Tags: c++, stdlist

Is there a better way of finding elements of a std::list that have the same value as manually going over the sorted list and comparing each element like this:

```
for(auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
        auto nextElement = it;
        nextElement++;

        if(nextElement == l.end())
            break;

        if(*it == *nextElement)
            cout << "Equal" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This solution has linear complexity, how much better do you expect to get?

Comment: is your list sorted?

Comment: What do you want to know?  How man unique values are in the list?  The spot of the all the duplicates of a particular value?  Which value is repeated the most?

Comment: you only search for adjacent entries that are equal?

Comment: [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) comes to mind.

Comment: @zigrazor read the question

Comment: @Shloim maybe some extra arguments for the sort command that say what to do if the elements are equal

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to know which elements have a value that is equal to the value of an other element.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 yes I do, because the list is sorted and then every equal value has to be adjacent to my current element

Comment: @Timo well this just removes every element that is equal to an other element. This is not what I need

Comment: Define "better way". `std::adjacent_find` could be more idiomatic (and may have parallel execution support). Less memory is virtually impossible. Shorter code - see NathanOliver's answer. Faster execution - profile?

Comment: @MaxLanghof it looks like `std::adjacent_find` is probably the best solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the STL algorithm [`adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find):

```cpp
auto it = l.begin()
while((it = std::adjacent_find(it, l.end())) != l.end()){
  std::cout << "Equal\n";
  ++it;
}
```

Comment: much better: `for (auto it = l.begin(), end = i.end(); ( it = std::adjacent_find(it, end) ) != end;)`. This avoids `it` having a wider scope if not needed and calling `end()` twice for each iteration, which might not be a trivial operation.

Comment: @user11914177 you won't get any better than linear complexity.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a really nice and compact way to get a list of all of the duplicates in a set of data, whether it is sorted or not.  What we can do is leverage `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` and use the elements value as the key for the map, and make the value a count of the number of times that value was "inserted".  That would look like

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> histogram;
for (auto e : l)
    ++histogram[e]; // gets a count of the number of duplicates
```

and then all you need to do is iterate the map and check for entries that have a mapped value greater than 1.  That would look like

```
for (const auto& pair : histogram)
    if (pair.second > 1)
        std::cout << "value: " << pair.first << " has " << pair.second << " matches.\n";
```

Using a `std::map` this is `O(NlogN + M)` and using an `unoredered_map` this is `O(N + M)` where `N` is the size of `l` and `M` is the size of `histogram`.

Comment: This looks like a good approach! 
But I want to edit the elements that have an equal value afterwards...

Comment: @user11914177 In that case you could change the last loop to something like `for (auto& e : l)
  if (histogram[e] > 1)
   do_something_to_e;`.  That said, since you know your list is sorted a simple linear traversal would probably be the fastest and easiest solution.

Comment: Using additional storage seems overkill when the list is *sorted* (according to the question).

Comment: @TobySpeight From the OP's response to my comment I assumed they wanted a list of the data, hence the extra storage.  Now that I see more of what they want to do I admit this is most likely overkill.  I'm going to leave it as it may help others but I've already suggest they use something else.

Comment: Yes, probably useful to others whose lists aren't sorted (and it may be more useful when we want to treat each group of duplicates together, rather than in pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the list is sorted, then `std::adjacent_find` will detect whether there are duplicates:

```
#include <algorithm>

if (std::adjacent_find(l.begin(), l.end()) != l.end()) {
    // we have at least one duplicate
}
```

If you wish to do something with all the duplicates, then we can loop over the pairs:

```
for (auto it = std::adjacent_find(l.begin(), l.end());
          it != l.end();
          it = std::adjacent_find(std::next(it), l.end())
{
    // *it and *std::next are duplicates (and there may be more)
}
```

It's possible that we want to find and process all of each group of identical elements together:

```
auto begin = std::adjacent_find(l.begin(), l.end());
while (begin != l.end()) {
    auto end = std::find_if_not(begin, l.end(),
                                [begin](auto n){ return n == *begin;});

    // All elements from begin (inclusive) to end (exclusive) are equal.
    // Process them here.

    begin = std::adjacent_find(end, l.end());
}
```

Comment: @user11914177, a portion exists (but with a serious bug still) in another answer, but this covers more range (pun intended!).

Comment: You posted your answer, that contains the same base idea, after the other answer. Yes that answer has a small bug in it, but I managed to fix it. Also your code is much more complex